# determine (in script) if command runs in terminal (from desktop file?)

Tags: command-line, .desktop

Simplified down, I want to write a shell function which runs a program in a new window. For applications like … emacs, firefox, gitk that can look like this:

```
myopen() {
  $@
}
```

But I want to open applications which run in the terminal in a new terminal, e.g. for alsamixer, vim, bash, zsh it should look like

```
myopen() {
  urxvt -e "$@"
}
```

I have seen that .desktop files contain the information if they should run in a terminal (for vim / gvim)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Vim
GenericName=Text Editor
TryExec=vim
Exec=vim %F
Terminal=true
```

or

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GVim
GenericName=Text Editor
TryExec=gvim
Exec=gvim -f %F
Terminal=false
```

is there an existing interface to query the `Terminal` filed (i.e. without using `locate` and `grep` to find the `.desktop` file and parsing them)?

So in quasi code I want to fill the gap in

```
myopen() {
  TERMINALFIELD=$(xdg-app-uses-terminal $1) # this line is made up
  if [[ TERMINALFIELD == true ]]; then
    urxvt -e "$@"
  else
    $@
  fi
  return $?
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Are you simply looking for a way to make an `alias` of those commands so they are run in a new terminal program?  What terminal program are you using?

Comment: `xdg-open` is the place to look.

Comment: @Julie Pelletier: kind of. so far I accumulated aliases like `vim_newwin='urxvt -e vim'`, `gvim_newwin=gvim` - such that any `_newwin` command would open in a new window. but i'd like something that provides the new window behaviour for any "new" command automatically, without the need for me to manually create the alias and check if i should launch the terminal or not. ("new" as in: unused by me before). and i thought about using a function to avoid piling up tons of aliases. I use `urxvt`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: I miss how to use `xdg-open` for this. afaik `xdg-open` can be used to open a file with the right application. like `xdg-open some.pdf` launches a pdf reader, but `xdg-open vim` doesn't launch vim in a new terminal - i merely get a popup message "/home/pseyfert/vim: file or directory not found". And I don't see any hint for other usages in the man page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `gtk-launch` will do what you want. It will launch an application using the information in the `.desktop` file. Here is some relevant information from the man page:

> **gtk-launch** takes at least one argument, the name of the application to launch. The name
>          should match application desktop file name, as residing in /usr/share/application, with or
>          without the '.desktop' suffix.