# How to specify which terminal is used by gtk-launch

Tags: terminal-emulator, .desktop

As discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332700/determine-in-script-if-command-runs-in-terminal-from-desktop-file), gtk-launch can launch applications either directly or in a terminal window, depending on whether the `.desktop` file specifies that the application runs in a terminal. It seems to me that this terminal is not the `x-terminal-emulator` from the alternative system (it doesn't change when I update the alternatives).

Is there a way to specify which terminal emulator `gtk-launch` should use?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't seem to be possible without workaround.

https://askubuntu.com/a/294430

Gtk-launch (a part of gtk) [is not related to `x-terminal-emulator` at all](https://gitlab.gnome.org/search?search=x-terminal-emulator&group_id=8&project_id=665&scope=&search_code=true&snippets=false&repository_ref=master&nav_source=navbar). In my case glib2 2.68.0 (behind gtk-launch) has its terminal choosing logic hardcoded in [prepend_terminal_to_vector()](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/2.68.0/gio/gdesktopappinfo.c#L2549) in gio/gdesktopappinfo.c.

```bsh
# Most preferred
gnome-terminal -- APP ARG1 ARG2 ...

# Then
mate-terminal  -x APP ARG1 ARG2 ...
xfce4-terminal -x APP ARG1 ARG2 ...

# After that
tilix       -e APP ARG1 ARG2 ...
konsole     -e APP ARG1 ARG2 ...
nxterm      -e APP ARG1 ARG2 ...
color-xterm -e APP ARG1 ARG2 ...
rxvt        -e APP ARG1 ARG2 ...
dtterm      -e APP ARG1 ARG2 ...

# Last resort
xterm -e APP ARG1 ARG2 ...
```

**A dirty workaround on my machine**

I want to invoke `alacritty -e ...`

1. Create a dummy gnome-terminal (α)

```bsh
sudo install -vDm755 /dev/null /usr/local/bin/gnome-terminal
```

2a. If you do NOT have `gnome-terminal` installed, put the following into α

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

[ x"$1" = x"--" ] || { exec /usr/bin/gnome-terminal "$@"; exit 0; }

shift

TITLE="$(basename "$1")"
if [ -n "$TITLE" ]; then
  /usr/bin/alacritty -t "$TITLE" -e "$@"
else
  /usr/bin/alacritty             -e "$@"
fi
```

2b. If you have `gnome-terminal` installed, put the following into α

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

[ x"$1" = x"--" ] || exit 1

shift

TITLE="$(basename "$1")"
if [ -n "$TITLE" ]; then
  /usr/bin/alacritty -t "$TITLE" -e "$@"
else
  /usr/bin/alacritty             -e "$@"
fi
```

*[askubuntu x-post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328341/634976)*

Answer (score 1):

As of GLib 2.75.0, the gnome-terminal workaround is no longer needed. This [commit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/commit/22e1b9bcc0ca7cd1ba2457ddf5b5545752f9c7ea) makes it possible to select the terminal of your choice using the `xdg-terminal-exec` wrapper.

##### xdg-terminal-exec

There is a [proposal](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2020-July/014340.html) for how freedesktop.org could specify an interface for starting a terminal. And a proposed implementation of [xdg-terminal-exec](https://github.com/Vladimir-csp/xdg-terminal-exec)

However, since it's only a proposal at the moment, it should be safe to write a custom `xdg-terminal-exec` wrapper.

##### Examples

###### foot terminal

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/foot $HOME/.local/bin/xdg-terminal-exec
```

###### alacritty

`xdg-terminal-exec`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec alacritty -e "$@"
```