# `xdg-open /` opens in browser when not already in terminal

Tags: xdg-open, file-browser

I have set default file manager to ranger (`xdg-mime query default inode/directory` = `ranger.desktop`). Yet, when I am not in the terminal already, `xdg-open /` opens in the browser.

I have checked in `/usr/share/applications/ranger.desktop` is `Terminal=true`. Setting `TERM=foot` (my terminal) in /etc/environment did not help, neither did linking my terminal to `/bin/xterm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xdg-open` will use the default handler `open_generic()` function if **your desktop environment cannot be detected or is not supported**. The default handler does not support the terminal well and would resort to using your default browser to open the url.

The `gio open` command from glib2 can be used instead, as it has better terminal support.

There are also other [alternatives](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Default_applications#Resource_openers) to xdg-open, most of which replace `/usr/bin/xdg-open`

Comment: what do I do with the `gio open`? I cannot change how some gui app decides to open a dir.

Comment: what is your DE?

Comment: sway (wayland) - window manager

To be clear, I know I can solve it by creating a custom `.desktop` with `Terminal=false` but I wanted a better solution, not worse

Comment: How do you use `xdg-open`, is it called from other programs?

Comment: I use a gtk app and it opens a directory. Idk how, I just know `xdg-open` can be used from the terminal to act the same. So I launch it from `rofi` (gui program launcher) and there it opens the browser just as all other gui apps. But when used in terminal already, it works fine.

Comment: What does `gio open /` command do in your system?

Comment: When I do not have anything linked to xterm, it errors out, otherwise launches the xterm linked program and opens ranger in it.

Comment: You can either set `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` to `"gnome"`, replace `/usr/bin/xdg-open` or create `/usr/local/bin/xdg-open` with a script that calls `gio open "$@"`. There are also other [alternatives](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Default_applications#Resource_openers) to xdg-open, most of which replace `/usr/bin/xdg-open`.

Comment: >>> When I do not have anything linked to xterm, it errors out, otherwise launches the xterm linked program and opens ranger in it. <<<


`gio` does not use `TERM`, `xdg-terminal-exec` can be used to configure the default terminal for it. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/748350/553564

Comment: I haven't thought of replacing an existing program. Yeah, that sounds fine, thanks.